# Can't find react-native package in external libraries

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

We have two modules named app and lib. Since we have to add rn into lib, we have added lib's build.gradle with :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules}
```

and in project's build.gradle

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
}}
```

and node_modules has been downloaded and put in the usual folder,with package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"react": "15.1.0",
"react-native": "0.28.0" }
```

and
`G:\dev>react-native -v
react-native-cli: 1.0.0
react-native: 0.28.0`

We event have

```
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" name="react-native-0.28.0" level="project" />
```

in the `lib.iml`, and can find react-native 0.28's dependencies like `okhttp-3.2.0` and `okio-1.8.0`(never used or added before) in studio's External Libraries,

But `react-native-0.28.0` never appears in studio's External Libraries and not valid for the code.

Any ideas why that happen? Thanks in advance.

**update**

After I put `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'` in app module's dependency `react-native-0.28.0` appears... that's very strange, Is that a bug or something?

Comment: Is the problem only that react-native doesn't appear in External Libraries in Android Studio? Or does the project fail to compile?

Does the app build fine from the command line?